# Is there something other than "if" and "else"

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-cracking

There are many ways for protecting a password like using strong algorithms like SHA-512, using salts, encrypting the database where the password is stored, packing the license file with UPX etc and etc but though there are various procedures **to my knowledge** successful login or success of purchase(in case it is a license code) ends like this for all types of logins, unlocking features etc.,

[image]

Though there are various methods for encrypting the password and making it stronger. It ultimately ends with an if and else. so modifying "if" will not be a big task for a reverse engineer so how does it work? Obfuscating just adds noise. Is there any specific way to replace the "if" and "else". Example is based on "C" language but it is common for all major languages like C++, Python, Java etc.,

Comment: Once compiled, these things become jumps, but yes, all licensing checking code (DRM) eventually comes down to some logical comparison. The client can do whatever it wants and can never fully be trusted. This is a fundamental fact that somehow has not deterred the sinking of billions of dollars into more and more failed DRM.

Comment: At least in C you need something like `if (strcmp (x,password) == 0)` instead of `x == password`.

Comment: @ott That is just an example based on "C" if it was "C" then I would have used string comparison but before I would compare string length(strlen) and would also change my words to comments //LOGIN OR UNLOCK FEATURES...

Comment: Using SHA512 or encrypting the database is not good ways to protect a password. You should use a password hashing algorithm like PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: *If you can change the program*, then of course you can make it do anything you want. You could make it accept the password "hunter2" for any user, or make it accept any password, or make it dance the Macarena. But how would you change the program when it's running on a server halfway across the world that you don't have the password to?

Answer (score 7):

It's a pretty safe bet that if an attacker has the ability to modify executable code on your server, you are already screwed. You are worrying about them bypassing the password validation to do something when they, to all intents and purposes, have complete control of your system already. If they didn't, they wouldn't be able to edit your binary executables.

If you've got this code client side rather than server side so they can mess with it, that is also a massive security hole. The code that validates of the password / password hash should absolutely not be able to be changed by an attacker.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is running on the user's machine, there is no foolproof way of preventing the user from reverse engineering and/or modifying the program. You can make it harder through obfuscation techniques, as anti-piracy and DRM tools attempt to do, but ultimately any program that the user runs is under the user's control.

The only definitive way around this problem is to have the `if statement` run on a machine that you can control. For instance, you might withhold important data necessary for your program to run, and require the client to connect to your server and provide valid credentials before your server supplies that data. Of course there are downsides to this as you can imagine - It requires the user to have an Internet connection for the program to work, and assumes there is actually important data you can withhold that is different from user to user.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course something other than "if". For example, you could calculate something that is vital for the program's correct execution from the password.

A table of function pointers that was encrypted with the password would be the most obvious thing to do, but it could be something more devious such as calculating the bounds of an array wrong.

So, if it is that easy, **why is not everybody doing that?**

For one reason, it makes the program much harder to debug, and having a pirated application crash unexpectedly is not exactly good PR (even if the program was pirated!).

But most importantly, you are wasting a lot of time on an arms race which you are inevitably going to lose (there are a lot of people with a lot of spare time available, and it is enough if *one of them* does a successful crack).
Instead, you could use to make your product better for *paying* customers.

The vast majority of people who pirate stuff will **never** pay you anyway, no matter what. That's annoying, but not much you can do.

But one or the other undecided paying customer might be convinced to pay if your software has that one other thing. Or an already existing customer might renew a license.